# How do i rearrage string recursively in java

Tags: java, string, recursion

i am trying to rearrange the contents of a string from a single line string of

> (file).DS_Store(~file)(folder)server(file).DS_Store(~file)(folder)test1(~folder)(folder)test2(~folder)(folder)test3(file).DS_Store(~file)(folder)test4(file).DS_Store(~file)(folder)test5(file).DS_Store(~file)(file)item.txt(~file)(~folder)(~folder)(~folder)(~folder)(file)text.txt(~file)

to a multiline string like

```
(file).DS_Store(~file)
(folder)client
    (folder)test6(~folder)
    (folder)test7
        (folder)test9
            (folder)test10
                (file)itemClient(~file)
            (~folder)
        (~folder)
    (~folder)
    (folder)test8(~folder)
(~folder)
(file)test.txt(~file)
(file)text.txt(~file)
```

I know that recursion would help me but when i try writing a recursive function it only checks the first delimiter and stops and does not check the rest of the string. This is the code i am using.

```
public String getFileStructure(String list, int level){
    String str = list;
    String ret = "";
    String fileStart = "(file)";
    String fileEnd = "(~file)";
    String folderStart = "(folder)";
    String folderEnd = "(~folder)";

    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
         for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
                ret+="\t";
            }
            if (str.startsWith(folderStart)) {
                ret+= "[" + str.substring(str.indexOf(folderStart)+8, str.indexOf(folderEnd)) + "]\n";
                getFileStructure(str, level + 1);
            } else {
                ret+= str.substring(str.indexOf(fileStart)+6, str.indexOf(fileEnd));
            }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

But it returns just

```
.DS_Store
.DS_Store
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT :

My original answer was completely wrong.

After further considering, I don't think recursion is a good idea in this case.
In order for recursion to work, whenever you encounter a folder start you must find the matching folder end and then recursively call the function with the content of the folder as the input.
However, in order to find which (~folder) marks the end of the current folder, you have to scan all the content of the folder. While doing it, you can already construct the output for the contend of the folder, so there's no point for the recursive call.

For example, say you have the structure (folder)A(file)a(~file)(folder)B(file)b(~file)(~folder)(folder)C(~folder)**(~folder)**(folder)D(~folder). I marked the end of folder A with bold font. In order to find it you must maintain a counter. Each time you find a (folder) string you increase the counter, and each time you find a (~folder) string to decrease it. Only when the counter goes back to the value it had before starting folder A, you've reached the end of that folder. While going over the string you can print all the content of folder A, using the counter to decide how many tabs are required for the indentation.

Comment: Still prints out the same output, could it be because i am using substring to cut the string? If so what alternatives are there which preserves the original and only cuts out the string i have appended to ret?

Comment: I completely changed my answer.

Comment: Thanks, would try it out and post my solution when i get round to it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the return value from getFileStructure:

ret += getFileStructure(...)